# My middleware doesn't work, instead of the text written inside of it in case of the error i get an error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rest, middleware

The idea is- in case if I have the 404 status I want to display a certain message "Cannot find the user" while I get:
"message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value "6424bb86f4be1059adf204881" (type string) at path "_id" for model "User"".
Why is it happening and how to fix if?
Thank you in advance!
Here is my code:
user.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   subscribedTo:{
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   userDate:{
      type: Date,
      required: true,
      default: Date.now()
   }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

users.js:

```
router.get('/:id', getUser, (req,res) => {
   res.send(res.user.name)
})
```

And my middleware itself:

```
async function getUser(req,res,next) {
   let user
   try{
      user = await User.findById(req.params.id)
      if(user == null) {
         return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Cannot find the user'})
      }
   } catch(err){
      return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message})
   }

   res.user = user
   next()
}
```

And in order to test the route I use the following code in me route.rest:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/users/6424bb86f4be1059adf20488
```

Comment: And what are you getting for `404` status? You showed the response which you are getting when the response status is `500` - the message you receive is `err.message`

Comment: If there in no user (wrong ID for instance) i must have `message: 'Cannot find the user'`

Comment: Do you need to pass `new ObjectId(req.params.id)` to the find by ID function instead of the raw ID string?